# Could someone confirm whether texture mapping in fragment shaders is supported on iPads running 3.2.x?

Tags: ipad, texture-mapping, fragment-shader, opengl-es

In the simulator I don't get any issues when testing under 3.2, however, on the device the texture doesn't show up. Under 4.2 it works fine, both in simulator and the device.

I'm trying to pinpoint the problem and wondering if someone could confirm whether there's a bug with that particular functionality in 3.2.x (iPad only). If you have other ideas as to what might be wrong, please let me know. I'm not very experience with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to confirm this, so I switched to using ES1 in iPad environment.